# Interactions with MVVM wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working with ComponentOne WPF Controls with MVVM Pattern.

I have the following in my ViewModel:

```
public ICommand ClientsEnter
{
    get
    {
        if (this.m_ClientsEnter == null)
        {
            this.m_ClientsEnter = new DelegateCommand<string>(ClientsLostFocusExecute, 
ClientsLostFocusCanExecute);
        }
        return m_ClientsEnter;
    }
}
```

And an observable collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<Client> Clients
{
    get { return m_Clients; }
    set
    {
        m_Clients = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Clients");
    }
}
```

In Xaml I have Added A ComponentOne Combo Box where I can enter ClientName Or ID and press enter to fire Event to execute ClientsEnter Command:

```
<Custom1:C1ComboBox  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="24" Name="cmbClients" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding 
    Clients, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedValuePath="ClientID" DisplayMemberPath="NameE" 
    IsEditable="True" Text="Enter Client Name Or ID" SelectedValue="{Binding 
    Path=Filter.ClientID, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="150" Margin="0,2" Width="189">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ei:KeyTrigger Key="enter"  FiredOn="KeyUp" ActiveOnFocus="True" SourceName=
            "cmbClients">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClientsEnter, Mode=OneWay}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding Text,ElementName=cmbClients}" 
                CommandName="KeyDown"/>
        </ei:KeyTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Custom1:C1ComboBox>
```

I need to know why it doesn't work, after pressing enter the clientID Disappears and nothing happens. Even the text="Enter Client Name Or ID" doesn't appear! Any ideas?
note that when i change the key to space it works but it doesnt take the text from combobox,

Comment: Are your command being called then user presses Enter? Can you also provide code for you command and DataContext of Combobox (your view model)

Comment: After spending 2 days investigating this issue ,i discover that there is a bug in C1Combobox as i replaced it with telerik Comboxbox and add the same trigger without changing anything in xaml except the control and it works fine.

finally,i dont recommend C1 wpf controls

Answer (score 1):

After spending 2 days investigating this issue ,i discover that there is a bug in C1Combobox as i replaced it with telerik Comboxbox and add the same trigger without changing anything in xaml except the control and it works fine.

finally,i dont recommend C1 wpf controls